# TUPLAS Y LISTA - PYTHON

Tags: python, lista, funciones, tuplas

Necesito crear una función que reciba por parámetros una tupla de tuplas y una lista de cadenas de caracteres. La tupla estará compuesta por tuplas de dos componentes, cada una de la forma (‘nombre’, ‘apellido’), y la lista, estará compuesta por cadenas de caracteres que representan nombres. Los “nombres” (tomados de cada tupla) que no estén en la lista, deberán ser agregados, por la función, en la lista. La función debe devolver un número que representa la cantidad de incorporaciones que se realizaron sobre la lista y no debe mostrar salidas en pantalla.

```
def agrega_nombres():
    tup_tuplas = (('Esteban', 'Kero') , ('Enrique', 'Cido') , ('Sara', 'Ampión') , ('Ana', 'Lista'))
    lis_cad = [ 'Luisa', 'Enrique', 'Hugo', 'Esteban' ]
    lista = list(tup_tuplas)
```

Lo que hice fue convertir la tupla a lista, luego, *¿Lo que tendría que hacer es unir ambas listas, formar una nueva sin que se repitan los nombres de ambas listas?*

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías, por favor, editar tu pregunta y añadir el código con lo qué has intentado? De esta forma la comunidad podrá colaborar con tu pregunta. Te invito a leer el siguiente enlace de cómo elaborar una buena pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres averiguar si un nombre está en la lista, usa la palabra `in`, asi:

```
if nombre in lista:
 ...
```

Igualmente, puedes preguntar si un nombre no está en la lista:

```
if nombre not in lista:
 ...
```

La función necesita recibir las tuplas y la lista como paràmetros, no tenerlos declarados en el cuerpo.

```
def agrega_nombres(tuplas, lista):
```

Dentro de la funciòn declaradas un contador de ocurrencias:

```
inserciones = 0
```

Luego recorres las tuplas. De cada tupla sacas el nombre y preguntas si está en la lista. En tal caso, lo agregas a la lista usando `append()` e incrementas el contador en uno.

Al final, retornas el contador con

```
return inserciones
```

No necesitas devolver la lista; esta se actualiza *in-situ*.

Resumiendo, la funciòn la usaras asi:

```
tup_tuplas = (('Esteban', 'Kero') , ('Enrique', 'Cido') , ('Sara', 'Ampión') , ('Ana', 'Lista'))
lis_cad = [ 'Luisa', 'Enrique', 'Hugo', 'Esteban' ]

x = agrega_nombres(tup_tuplas, lis_cad)            
print("Inserciones", x)
print(lis_cad)
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación, me sirvo bastante.